# Network request error setTimeout$argument_0

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fetch

I'm using React Native and Node js to build an app.

When I try to send 'POST' request, I get an ERROR to the Command:

setTimeout$argument_0.

The full Error:

Network request failed

- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:527:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

- [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

The code:

```
    fetch('myIP:3000/signup',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'email':values.email,
                'password': values.password
            })
        })
        .then(res=>{res.json()})
        .then(data=>console.log('reach! ' + data))
        .catch((err)=> console.log(err))
```

Edit: adding the fetch code

```
const { mongoURI } = require('./keys');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require("./models/User");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(express.json());

// database connection
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex:true })
  .then((result) => {app.listen(PORT); console.log('connected server ' + PORT)})
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.create({ email, password });
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
    res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
   
  }
  catch(err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
})
```

Anyone who knows how to solve that error?

Comment: How are you handling the response? include your code. Do you get an error on your NodeJS server?

Comment: Not getting error on NodeJs server,
Im handling the response very simply:

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.send('got POST request ');
  console.log('got POST request ');
}

Right now just trying to be able to commiunicate between the two.

Comment: ... post your full fetch code

Comment: Edited and Added the full code :)

Comment: actually I wanted the fetch code. so the code at the top what happens after your fetch call?

Comment: So after fetch("myIP:3000/signup", ({...}) after here

Comment: ohh, just updated

Comment: Do you get anything in Data? or just the error

Comment: Get only the error message

Comment: Look into an Mongoose tutorial to see if your calls are correct - I have no idea of mongoose unfortunally. you can also try to use postman which is a great tool for testing api calls.

Comment: Found something.
The problem is that I use expo app, and the LAN option is not working for me,
so I use the Tunnel option which is not support fetch and network communication.

Comment: Great to here - good luck!